# gdal_translate -projwin performance slow when using VRT

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, vrt

I'm using `gdal_translate` to clip 5x5 degree tiles from a raster.

I have 4 large rasters-- one for South America, and 4 that divide Africa and Asia into 4 separate pieces. Each raster is a Byte, in WGS84, and has values of 1 (land) and NoData (ocean). I can extract a tile from South America like so:

`gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 11% -projwin 10.0 -5.0 15.0 -10.0 1.tif my_tile.tif`

This takes 40 seconds.

I also have a VRT of all the rasters together, South America and the four other tifs that compose Africa/Asia. To create the same tile, I do:

`gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 11% -projwin 10.0 -5.0 15.0 -10.0 gadm0.vrt my_tile.tif`

This takes 3 minutes.

Is this expected? Is there any way to cut down on the overhead caused by the VRT dataset? Happy to provide the actual raster data if that helps.

---

EDIT: See this link for the data associated data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y20gzv627kyjlwx/SE_Test_VRT_Data.zip?dl=0

Comment: Actual data would help.

Comment: @user30184 i've edited my post-- see the link above. thanks for your help!

Comment: @CharlieLefrak Did you figure out why exporting from VRT is much slower than passing in the files directly? I'm seeing slow exports from VRT and temporary layers in QGIS versus directly saving to a file during operations.

Comment: I never did @ansonl- let me know if you figure it out!